# I want to add delay between jumps in my platforming game

Tags: python, pygame, 2d

So i have this platforming game that im programming in pygame. I have a jump method and i want to add a dely between jumps. That way i dont keep jumping into the ceiling. Heres the code

```
def jump(self):
    if (self.onGround == True):

        return

    self.velocity = 10
    self.onGround = False
```

This is what calls it in the main game loop:

```
if (event.key==pygame.K_UP):

    player.jump()
```

Comment: As a side note, don't put parentheses around `if` conditions in Python. Also, you almost never want `== True`; just use `if self.onGround:`. See [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the last time you jumped, or of the next time you're allowed to jump (with [`pygame.time`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html)):

```
def __init__(self, …):
    # ...
    self.next_jump = 0

def jump(self):
    if pygame.time.get_ticks() < self.next_jump:
        return
    # ...
    self.next_jump = pygame.time.getticks() + 500
```

Depending on which type of loop you've gone with (traditional event loop, frame-rate-limited loop, unlimited-frame-rate loop) there may be better answers involving, e.g., setting a timer or using a `Clock`, but this will work with any type.